# Query String not retrieving values in servlet page

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am sending two values by using Query string using both jsp and servlet pages.

1. I need to taking only one value from query string in jsp page working fine.
2. At the same time in servlet page when i click button i need to get the value 
   from query string but here i am not getting the value from query string.
3. which value is i need to took in jsp that value only it visible remaining value 
   is appear in servlet page.
4. how can i retrieving query string values in my servlet

In jsp i am using query string at the text box value code:

```
<input type="text" id="txtBatchName" name="txtBatchName" value="<%=request.getParameter("BatchId").replace("id=","")%>">
```

Servlet page:

```
if(request.getParameter("btnUpdate")!= null){
String Batch2=request.getQueryString();
String Id1=request.getParameter("Id");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with name attribute.(Id is specific to Java Script and it wont be transmitted to server side)

```
String Id1=request.getParameter("txtBatchName");
```

Comment: No, In my query string having both `Id and BatchId` but i need `BatchId in jsp` and `Id value in servlet page`

Comment: Can you post your HTML Form ? id parameter cannot serialize by html itself to the server.